# docusign recepient status not getting created

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am using a demo instance of docusign connect for my development on salesforce platform. I noticed that Docusign Recipient Status record is not getting created. Docusing Status record which is the parent object is getting created thought. Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Thanks,

Comment: It sounds like there's an issue with your setup. If you haven't already, I would contact DocuSign Customer Support

Comment: Will you attach your most recent Connect log when this issue occurs? Typically these logs will reference the Recipient Status query attempting to run with any exceptions it may have ran into.